# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference in Fragment

Tags: android

When i show dialog, then i dismis, and i show dialog again, dialog error, imganhsp == null. How to fix it guys ! thanks

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/anhsp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/imageadd"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtTen"
            android:hint="Tên sản phẩm"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtMota"
            android:hint="Mô tả sản phẩm"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtgia"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Giá sản phẩm"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHuy"
                android:text="Hủy"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonXacNhan"
                android:text="Xác nhận thêm"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.asus.banhangonline.FragmentUngDung.FragmentTabHost.FraAlbum"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/layout_album" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**My Code:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view != null) {
        parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfrg_themsp, container, false);

    } catch (InflateException e) {

    }
      AnhXa();
      return view;
}


private void AnhXa() {
    imganhsp = (ImageView)  view.findViewById(R.id.anhsp); // <--- null
    btnHuy = (Button)        view.findViewById(R.id.buttonHuy);
    btnXacNhan = (Button)   view.findViewById(R.id.buttonXacNhan);
    edtten = (EditText)     view.findViewById(R.id.edtTen);
    edtmota = (EditText)     view.findViewById(R.id.edtMota);
    edtgia = (EditText)     view.findViewById(R.id.edtgia);
}
```

When i show dialog, then i dismis, and i show dialog again, dialog error, imganhsp == null.

Comment: Can you post your dialog showing code and from where do you call `AnhXa `?

Comment: i already edit it ! AnhXa(); in onCreateView

Comment: Why do you have a`if (view != null) {
            parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
        }`...and why is your `view` inflation in try/catch block?

Comment: u try show dialog then cancel , it will error... tag null ...